# How to show the correct title for my blog post and not just the latest title using markdown

Tags: html, markdown, blogs

I am trying to creating a blog on my website using markdown but I am having trouble with the blog titles.
I have created a loop to bring in the latest title and excerpt onto my home page which works fine.: 
{% for post in site.posts limit: 1 %}

On my site I have a list of my blogs (https://jenjnif.github.io/blog.html) 
and when you click on one to read the whole blog I would the title for only that blog to show up.

I used the same code as above {% for post in site.posts limit: 1 %} to only show one title as all blog titles were showing without this but obviously then it will only show the latest title regardless of which blog I am actually viewing. Here is the markdown for that page:

---

layout: default

---

```html
<div id="post">
<div class="blog-header">
   {% for post in site.posts limit: 1 %}
</div>
<h2 class="blog-title">{{ post.title }}</h2>
{% endfor %}
{{ content }}
</div>
```

I know the limit: 1 will not work because it is only then going to take the latest title but I don't know how else to get only one title showing up on each blog post. Is there a way to make sure only one title shows - only showing the correct, current blog title, not all of them?
All files can be found in my GitHub repository: https://github.com/jenjnif/jenjnif.github.io

Comment: Have you tried `page.title` instead of the for loop? Looks like you're using [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/) to build the site?

Comment: So simple but it worked! Thank you so much. Yes, decided to try to build it in Jekyll as part of a project to learn about how it all works. I have only recently started learning about any kind of development and I just couldn't find anything to help me after hours of searching on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Jekyll and its Liquid templating engine, they have several [sets of variables](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/). Instead of using a for loop to go through all the posts, you can use `page.title` to get the title for the current blog post.

```
<div id="post">
<div class="blog-header">
</div>
<h2 class="blog-title">{{ page.title }}</h2>
{{ content }}
</div>
```